# JPA @Query retrieving no results

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have a list of data in tbcaseaccount which I wanted to group by team. Those who has no team yet(null) should be labeled as 'Unassigned'.

I tried retrieving all first since all records has null values for team anyway using this query:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.eteligent.form.delinquencyBucketForm('Unassigned'" +
            "ELSE acct.team.teamName END, COUNT(acct)" +
            "FROM TbCaseAccount acct " +
            "WHERE acct.loan.ddlq >= :start AND acct.loan.ddlq <= :ends " +
            "GROUP by acct.team")
    List<delinquencyBucketForm> findByDdlqBetweenDdlqForm(@Param("start") long start, @Param("ends")long ends);
```

And successfully retrieved the data with the following format:

```
[{"team":"Unassigned","qty":8639,"totalunpaid":26754051.3400}]
```

However, when I try to insert a case condition in the query, I am getting no results, just an empty pair of square brackets:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.eteligent.form.delinquencyBucketForm(CASE WHEN acct.team.teamName IS NULL THEN 'Unassigned'" +
        "ELSE acct.team.teamName END, COUNT(acct)" +
        "FROM TbCaseAccount acct " +
        "WHERE acct.loan.ddlq >= :start AND acct.loan.ddlq <= :ends " +
        "GROUP by acct.team.teamName")
List<delinquencyBucketForm> findByDdlqBetweenDdlqForm(@Param("start") long start, @Param("ends")long ends);
```

TbCaseAccount

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tbloans_id")
private Tbloans loan;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "team")
private TbTeam team;
```

TbTeam

```
@Column(name = "team_name", length = 30)
private String teamName;
```

delinquencyBucketForm

```
public class delinquencyBucketForm {
String team;
long qty;
BigDecimal totalunpaid;

public delinquencyBucketForm(String team,long qty, Double totalunpaid) {
    this.qty = qty;
    this.totalunpaid = new BigDecimal(totalunpaid).setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    this.team = team;
}
//getters and setters...
```

Comment: How to close this question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to solve it. I just needed to use LEFT JOIN since upon looking to the converted sql in the logs, it uses cross joins in the query. Here is my updated query.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.eteligent.form.delinquencyBucketForm(CASE WHEN team.teamName IS NULL THEN 'Unassigned'" +
        "ELSE team.teamName END, COUNT(acct)" +
        "FROM TbCaseAccount acct LEFT JOIN acct.loan loan LEFT JOIN acct.team team" +
        "WHERE acct.loan.ddlq >= :start AND acct.loan.ddlq <= :ends " +
        "GROUP by team.teamName")
List<delinquencyBucketForm> findByDdlqBetweenDdlqForm(@Param("start") long start, @Param("ends")long ends);
```